# XPages Navigation - Updating Panels with Link onclick Events

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to deploy "Building a Configurable and Extensible XPages Navigation" I found in THE VIEW (I'm a subscriber):

http://www.eview.com/eview/volr6.nsf/articleURL/2012-09-building-a-configurable-and-extensible-xpages-navigation.

My design is very basic and traditional: two panels. In the left panel a Custom Control with the navigation as links. In the right panel an "Include Page" control for displaying XPages as a result of onclick events of the links in the left panel.

Problem: can't get the the right panel to update.

Have tried, in vain: passing sessionScope parameter with SSJS, partial updates, postScript with partialRefreshGet.

MY CODE:
My "almost" working version - needs a manual refresh/reload to actually display the desired XPage in the right panel's "Include Page" control.

Link onclick: sessionScope.showPage = "xspByYear.xsp"; AND Partial Update of right panel.

Right panel's "Include Page" - pageName AND onClientLoad (with Home as default):

```
var tmp = sessionScope.showPage;
if (tmp == null){
    "xspHome.xsp";
} else {
    tmp;
}
```

Comment: All Properties/pageName had an "$" added, not allowed to change to "#": "... cannot be a run time binding."

Comment: Do you have any of your code to show us so we can see if theres a problem?

Comment: Rolf, please update your question with your code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the "Include Page" control to a panel. Set an id to the panel and refresh the panel in the onclick event of the links (Partial Update).

```
<xp:panel id="panelToUpdate">
        <xp:include pageName="/MyXPage.xsp" id="include1"></xp:include>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean concretely by: You can pass the "Include Page" control to a panel.

Comment: I think he just means you can place it inside a panel. In many situations, partial refresh works best when the content you want to refresh is placed inside a panel, and you refresh the panel instead. It's worth a try as a starting point

Comment: Thanks Brian, the "Include Page" is in a Panel, which is in a Table Cell.The navigator Custom Control is positioned likewise. I'm unable to refresh the "Include Page" with the contents to be displayed according to the link onclick event of the navigator. I like the THE WIEW solution, and would like to deploy it, pls cf. also my initial posting.